# Confused about correct naming of Datatypes in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, types

I have a question about PowerShell. I read documentation that datatypes in PowerShell are strings, ints etc. But how would you call the objects that are created for instance when I instantiate an object in PowerShell like so `$Object = Get-Process -Name 'NotePad'`

What would the correct name be for $object, would this also be called a Data Type?

Kind regards,

John

Comment: `$Object.GetType().FullName` should equal to `System.Diagnostics.Process` in this particular case.

Comment: Are you asking how to know the _type name_ of an object, or about appropriate variable naming?

Comment: Hi Notjustme and Mathias, thanks for answering. My question would be to clarify would be are they all datatypes? Can I say $object (in the case above) is of datatype System.Diagnostics.Process in PowerShell? And for instance [int]$number = 10 that $number is of dadatype system.int32? So is everything considered a datatype?

Comment: If we see the Get-Process doc we can read "By default, this cmdlet returns a System.Diagnostics.Process object". I think we speak about objects. Simply. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-process?view=powershell-7. Is it you question ?

Comment: @fearfulgb123s yes, more or less. PowerShell's type system is a direct extension of .NET's common type system (same type system as in C#, F# or VB.NET). Everything is an object, and each object has an intrinsic _type_, in the case of `$object` in your example, the type is `System.Diagnostics.Process`. Any and all objects expose the `GetType()` method, making it easy to interrogate exactly which type an object is :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PowerShell is built using dotnet, an object oriented programming (OOP) framework.  Everything in an OOP is an Object, and objects can have many properties.

The properties of an object can be of many different datatypes, like boolean (true false), string( "SomeString") or an int (1).  [Here's the list of the most common basic datatypes.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/data-types/)

Some of the properties might be collections of other rich objects while some could be just string.

So to say is everything in PowerShell a datatype?  I can unwind that question to instead ask

#### *What is everything in PowerShell?*

Everything in PowerShell is a dotnet object, which might be a single, or a collection of many different datatypes.

In the case of your example.

```
>(Get-Process notepad).GetType() | 
   Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName 

System.Diagnostics.Process
```

PowerShell returns an object which is of the [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netframework-4.8) datatype.

Comment: a little more detail, why MS speaks of datatype for Powershell and not type ?

Comment: Type is short for datatype?  Programmers like to save time and keystrokes.  After all, they say that while necessity is the mother of all invention, laziness is the father.

Comment: Ok  thanks a lot all of you I have to say I'm happy with the answer and comments